# How can I exit a function, without exiting the file

Tags: shell-script, terminal, function

Hi i am creating a subshell in Unix with functions, but when i execute a function it finishes the process. I want to know how can I exit a function without exiting the subshell.

Comment: Have your ran the script through `shellcheck`?

Comment: The code is long. Strip it back to the smallest program that you can make that still exhibits the same problem. Then post the code, tell us the expected behaviour and tell us what happened.

Comment: My comment is **not** a call for you to delete the code. Can you replace the code with a smaller example, that exhibits the **same** problem.

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing what this program should do, it is hard to debug.

My guess is that you are using `exit` when you should be using `return`. `exit` exits the script. `return` exits the function.

Comment: The only code that could be relevant is in comando_bakmove(), which shows your guess to appear correct (function exits 1 or 0).

Comment: @dcwaters yes it is a guess. However it is also what I guessed before I read the code. The OP needs to be clearer in the question (see comments on question).